# Clientes que compraram em um ano mas não em outro

Tags: mysql, query, select

Preciso fazer um select que me traga quais os clientes que compraram em 2016 e não compraram em 2017 e vice-versa.

Este é o meu select:

```
SELECT
tc.`cod-emitente` AS CODIGO,
tc.`nome-emit` AS CLIENTE,
fg.`ano` AS ANO 
FROM tb_clientes tc 
LEFT JOIN faturamento_global fg ON (tc.`cod-emitente` = fg.`cod-emitente`) 
WHERE fg.`ano` >= 2016 
GROUP BY fg.`cod-emitente`, fg.`ano`
```

Ele me traz o seguinte:

```
CODIGO CLIENTE ANO
14  CLIENTE1    2016
14  CLIENTE1    2017
15  CLIENTE2    2016
15  CLIENTE2    2017
27  CLIENTE3    2016
35  CLIENTE4    2016
35  CLIENTE4    2017
```

Perceba que o cliente com código 27 comprou somente em 2016 e é uma lista com clientes deste tipo que eu preciso.

Comment: Você precisa clarear um pouco sua pergunta mostrando, por exemplo, situações em que a sua condição seja satisfeita.

Comment: Você não pode colocar os dados que tem nessa tabela na sua pergunta pra facilitar o entendimento?

Comment: Executei desta forma, porém, trouxe o resultado que coloquei no post inicial, agora preciso separar qual cliente comprou apenas em um ano e não em outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` para verificar se existe outro faturamento diferente do ano em questão:

```
SELECT tc.`cod-emitente` AS CODIGO,
       tc.`nome-emit` AS CLIENTE,
       fg.`ano` AS ANO
  FROM tb_clientes tc
       LEFT JOIN faturamento_global fg ON tc.`cod-emitente` = fg.`cod-emitente`
 WHERE fg.`ano`>= 2016
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM faturamento_global fg2
                   WHERE fg2.`cod-emitente` = fg.`cod-emitente`
                     AND fg2.`ano` <> fg.`ano`)
 GROUP BY fg.`cod-emitente`, fg.`ano`
```

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

Answer (score 0):

Poderia explicar melhor a sua estrutura? Existe alguma chave estrangeira? O ideal seria você ter uma tabela somente com cadastro de clientes e outra tabela com as compras, assim você conseguiria fazer com LEFT JOIN, por exemplo:

```
SELECT clientes.id,clientes.nome,compras.ano 

FROM clientes 

LEFT JOIN compras ON (clientes.id = compras.FK_cliente_id)

WHERE ...
```